# difference between procedure and stored procedure sql server?

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between a procedure and a stored procedure on sql server?

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference. There is no concept of "unstored" procedures in SQL Server.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
```

Will create a stored procedure

```
select * from sys.procedures
```

will show you the stored procedures.

This is as opposed to sending adhoc sql statements or [prepared sql](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ParameterizingAdHocSQL.aspx) statements.

Answer (score 2):

A procedure is a specified series of actions, acts or operations which have to be executed in the same manner in order to always obtain the same result under the same circumstances

A stored procedure is a subroutine available to applications accessing a relational database system. Stored procedures (sometimes called a proc, sproc, StoPro, or SP) are actually stored in the database data dictionary.

n a procedure you have to start the transaction manually, allowing the rollback manually and stuff like that.

In a stored procedure, usually the DBA system takes care of the main transaction in case of errors. You can even use atomic transactions to keep your information consistent.

Then, A stored procedure is execute a bit faster than a single procedure because of the indexing in the dba.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an actual procedure, in the database, it's a stored procedure -- regardless of whether people pronounce the "stored" part.

Stored procedures are in opposition to the client's issuing the SQL statements of the procedure one by one.  That's what an un-"stored procedure" would be.